# Getting an Element Inside ng-repeat with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am writing e2e tests for an app I am working on and I am trying to write a test for alerts generated by the alert directive (Angular UI Bootstrap) from within a wrapper directive. Here is the code I have written so far:

First we have the wrapper directive for generating alerts

```
// Grab our directive controller
// The controller just contains the alert functions for the Angular UI     
// Bootstrap alerts directive
import InfoAlertController from './info-alert.controller.js';

let moduleName = 'infoAlert';

// ## Directive Definition
class InfoAlert {

    constructor() {

        this.template =
        `
            <div>

                <alert
                    ng-repeat="alert in vm.alerts"
                    type="{{ alert.type }}"
                    close="vm.closeAlert($index)" >

                        {{ alert.msg }}

                </alert>

            </div>
        `;
        this.restrict = 'E';
        this.scope = {};
        this.bindToController = {

            name : '@?'
        };
        this.transclude = true;
        this.controller = InfoAlertController;
        this.controllerAs = 'vm';
    }

    // ### Optional Link Function
    link (scope, elem, attrs, vm, transclude) {

    }
}

export default [moduleName, directiveFactory(InfoAlert)];
```

Here is the directive being implemented in the `user login` component view

```
<info-alert
     name="loginAlerts">
</info-alert>
```

The `user login` component is another directive which contains a form with Angular validation that interacts with an Authentication service.

Here is the test that I am trying to write

```
describe('login component', () => {

    it('should display an error after failedauthentication', () => {

            browser.get('/login');

            element(by.model('vm.user.username')).sendKeys('nerfherder');

            element(by.model('vm.user.password')).sendKeys('badpassword');

            element(by.css('.btn-custom')).click();

            let e = element(by.repeater('alert in vm.alerts').row(0));

            // This is always fails no matter what I try
            expect(e.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

The error I get is `Expected 0 to be greater than 0` which I assume means it isn't finding the alerts using the method I am employing. I have also tried targeting the alerts by their class `element(by.css('.alert-danger'));` and
`element(by.css('.alert'));` respectively. Neither does it work with `browser.waitForAngular();`.

I have also tried an implementation of the Protractor Expected Conditions to no avail.

All of the functionality works with hand testing and the alert pops up during test execution. Any help would be much appreciated as this developer is stumped.

**Solution**

This solution is based on alecxe's answer below:

```
describe('login component', () => {

    it('should display an error after failed authentication', () => {

        let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

        browser.get('/login');

        element(by.model('vm.user.username')).sendKeys('nerfherder');

        element(by.model('vm.user.password')).sendKeys('badpassword');

        let alert = element(by.repeater('alert in vm.alerts').row(0));

        let alertLoaded = EC.visibilityOf(alert);

        element(by.css('.btn-custom')).click();

        // UI Bootstrap alert class
        let e = element(by.css('.alert-danger'));

        browser.wait(alertLoaded, 5000);

        expect(e.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

The test now passes fine.

Comment: How is this question ES6 related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to *explicitly wait for the alert to appear*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.repeater('alert in vm.alerts'))), 5000);
```

Comment: If I use this implementation of Protractor's Expected Conditions, I get  `- Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined;`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @datatype_void I've updated the answer, check it out.

Comment: Now it fails with `- Failed: Wait timed out after 5334ms`

Comment: I know that the alerts work correctly and that I am using the correct string for targeting the element. I don't know why it can't find it...

Comment: @datatype_void how about: `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.tagName('alert'))), 5000);`?

Comment: That one fails with `- Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`

Comment: Sorry that was my bad, it does work if I use your updated solution if I tweak one other thing. My updated question has the updated code. Thanks again man!

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
let e = element.all(by.repeater('alert in vm.alerts').row(0));
```

Comment: If I use this solution the test fails with `- Expected [ ] to be true`